# integrate images in TYPO3 backend module

Tags: php, typo3

I'm trying to create a little Extension with frondend-/ backend plugin and it's working pretty well. My problem now is that i want to have the same mechanics of "list view" in my own backend module.

In the "list view" of TYPO3 it's pretty easy to select, edit, delete an image, shown in the screenshot below. But how is this working in my own backend module? I'm searching the whole afternoon now but I can't find any hint about this.

[image]

best regards
blue

Comment: You should not edit records on your own, but you should use the `FormEngine` for that. Then the usual rules for TCA apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can check reference of FAL in TYPO3

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/Index.html